# what python feature is illustrated in this code?

Tags: python, language-features

I read Storm ORM's tutorial at https://storm.canonical.com/Tutorial, and I stumbled upon the following piece of code :

```
store.find(Person, Person.name == u"Mary Margaret").set(name=u"Mary Maggie")
```

I'm not sure that the second argument of the **find** method will be evaluated to True/False. I think it will be interpreted as a lambda. If that is true, how can I achieve the same effect in my functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I'm a Java programmer... I'm guessing... 
it is operator overloading? Person.name == is an operator overloaded that instead do comparison... it produces a SQL query

my 0.02$

Comment: Java and operator overloading ... don't think it will ever come true. On the other side, maybe you are right .

Comment: Odd.... Accepting a "guessing" answer when another answer is based on the actual source code in Storm.

Comment: sorry, but my guess was "fast enough" :-) PS you're right, it's very odd!

Comment: In fairness, the guessing answer *is* correct, even if it's not the most clear.

Answer (score 22):

`Person.name` has a overloaded `__eq__` method that returns not a boolean value but an object that stores both sides of the expression; that object can be examined by the `find()` method to obtain the attribute and value that it will use for filtering.  I would describe this as a type of lazy evaluation pattern.

In Storm, it is implemented with the [`Comparable` object](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Estorm/storm/trunk/annotate/head%3A/storm/expr.py#L380).

Answer (score 9):

`Person.name` is an instance of some type with a custom `__eq__` method. While `__eq__` normally returns a boolean(ish) value, it can actually return whatever you want, including a lambda. See [Python special method names](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) for more on this and related methods.

Probably the most confusing/misleading part of this (especially if you're used to other OO languages like Java) is that `Person.name` and `person.name` (where `person` is an instance of `Person`) don't have to have any relationship to each other. For example:

```
class Person(object):
  name = "name of class"
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "name of instance"

person = Person()
print Person.name
print person.name
```

This will print:

> ```
> name of class
> name of instance
> ```

Note that the class property is just set in the class body, while the instance property is set in the `__init__` method.

In your case, you'd set `Person.name` to the object with the custom `__eq__` method that returns a lambda, something like this:

```
class LambdaThingy(object):
  def __init__(self, attrname):
    self.__attrname = attrname

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return lambda x: getattr(x, self.__attrname) == other

class Person(object):
  name = LambdaThingy('name')

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

equals_fred = Person.name == "Fred"
equals_barney = Person.name == "Barney"

fred = Person("Fred")

print equals_fred(fred)
print equals_barney(fred)
```

This prints:

```
True
False
```

This is certainly skirting the edge of being "too clever", so I'd be very cautious about using this in production code. An explicit lambda would probably be a lot clearer to future maintainers, even if it is a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 8):

The magic is in the Person.name property, which results in a type that overloads `__eq__` (&c) to return non-bools.  Storm's sources are online for you to browse (and CAUTIOUSLY imitate;-) at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~storm/storm/trunk/files/head%3A/storm/ -- as you'll see, they don't go light on the "black magic";-)

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like a python lambda to me. I did not read the code for Storm but Miles is probably right in that it uses a lazy evaluation schema.

To learn more about python lambda functions read the excellent [chapter](http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) of [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/index.html).

Comment: I always thought that lambda functions had to be prefixed by the lambda keyword, so this could not be the case, right?